# window.open ignoring width and height

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

When you click a "select customer" button it opens a new window for you to search for a customer. The new window works correctly on IE and has **width 300, height 200.** On Chrome it opens with **width 1350, height 664**. This is the current code that runs onClick:

```
window.open('/servlet/urlForThePage', 'titleOfThePage', 'width=300,height=200,scrollbars');
```

I've looked at similar issues and my parameters are in a single string separated by commas, and my notation for everything seems to be correct. I've tried using

```
width=300px,height=200px, window.innerWidth=300, window.innerHeight=200, window.innerWidth=300px, window.innerHeight=200px
```

as well as combinations of all of the above.

The window still opens at nearly full screen.

Comment: The first line you provided works fine for me in Chrome. I changed the url to https://google.com in order to test it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the version or the /servlet/ that's messing it up then. We're on Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I've tried it on 3 coworkers computers - on all of ours it opens nearly full screen instead of 300x200